# Python3 google spreadsheet api batchUpdate Json formatting

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-sheets

I want to use google spreadsheet api batchUpdate to update different values with the same request.

In the documentation examples they use a dict to store the Json request but I need to set the same attribute (insertDimension) multiple times. 
Here Google expected request

> ```
> {
>   "requests": [
>     {
>       "insertDimension": {
>         "range": {
>           "sheetId": sheetId,
>           "dimension": "COLUMNS",
>           "startIndex": 2,
>           "endIndex": 4
>         },
>         "inheritBefore": true
>       }
>     },
>     {
>       "insertDimension": {
>         "range": {
>           "sheetId": sheetId,
>           "dimension": "ROWS",
>           "startIndex": 0,
>           "endIndex": 3
>         },
>         "inheritBefore": false
>       }
>     },
>   ],
> }
> ```

I tried using json.dumps

> mydata = json.dumps('''
>
> "requests": [{{"updateDimensionProperties": {"range": {"sheetId": 0,"dimension": "ROWS","startIndex": 0
>             "endIndex": 50
>           },
>           "properties": {
>             "pixelSize": 10
>           },
>           "fields": "pixelSize"
>         }
>       }
>           }   ] ''')

but I receive this error message
*"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "": Root element must be a message."*

Answer (score 0):

Your request is invalid because it never says what kind of request it is: the `insertDimension` request. The correct form is

```
{
"requests": [
  {
  "insertDimension": { 
    # required fields at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#InsertDimensionRequest
  }
  },
  {
  "insertDimension": { 
    # required fields at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#InsertDimensionRequest
  }
  }]
}
```

By the way, one of the fields is `inheritFromBefore`, not `inheritBefore`